# Get info from another application

Tags: c#, window, pinvoke

Basically what i want to do is see the value of a progress bar in an application from another application, If its possible.

I have been able to find the progress bar from my app with and get the WINDOWINFO:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool GetWindowInfo(IntPtr hwnd, ref WINDOWINFO pwi);
```

But I'm not sure how or if its possible to get the value.

WINDOWINFO is explained [here](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures.WINDOWINFO) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632610%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Any help or other ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Use `RangeValuePattern`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetWindowInfo` isn't going to tell you anything specific to a progress bar - only the standard window flags.   Take a look at the documentation for [Progress Bar Messages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff485990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for how to interact with a progress bar.

You need to use the [PBM_GETPOS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760830%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message to get the current position of a progress bar as below:

```
const uint PBM_GETPOS = 0x0408;
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr GetWindowInfo(IntPtr hwnd, uint msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

uint pos = (uint)SendMessage(hwnd, PBM_GETPOS, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
```

Comment: you forgot to add your PGM_GETPOS message to your SendMessage call

Comment: You'll probably want to use `PBM_GETRANGE` too

Comment: He certainly does.  That's where it gets *difficult*, the lParam pointer needs to be valid in the other process.  This answer isn't going to help him.  Raymond's brief comment does.

Comment: @HansPassant You can pass `NULL` for the pointer in `PBM_GETRANGE` and get the value from `SendMessage` return value. As usual, automation is a better option.